# Vlookup conditional formatting rule to highlight matched cells not properly executing

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I have two columns of numbers and am using conditional formatting to highlight fill the cells in column Z that are found in column AA. My conditional formatting rule is a vlookup ->

```
=VLOOKUP($W4,$AA4:$AA478,1,FALSE)
```

For example, `W257` is `CK#276` and `AA269` is also `CK#276`. The entire columns are formatted as Number, so this shouldn't be the issue. I also removed excess spaces just in case. When I test the vlookup specific to this example `(=VLOOKUP(W257,AA263:AA276,1,FALSE))` it finds the value correctly, however with the full vlookup it does not highlight the cell.

I am unsure what could be causing this. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the data in column `AA` is only in rows `4` to `478`, you need to change: `$AA4:$AA478` to `$AA$4:$AA$478`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried this, however nothing changed